# Setting names for vector elements

Tags: r

I am want to create a function that gets a string and returns a vector with the number of times every element appears. Now every value has to get a name.
So for example `answer=function("abcda")` should return

```
a b c d
2 1 1 1
```

Where `answer` is a vector and every number has a name.
My problem is when I try to use the `names` function I get something like this

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]     1    1    1    1
attr(,"names")
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Now when I the names function on console it works but when I use it within the function it is wrong.

Comment: Please take time to format your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this easily with a combination of `strsplit` and `table`. Use `""` as the character to split on, which will split the string into single characters.

Example:

```
table(strsplit("abcda", ""))
## 
## a b c d 
## 2 1 1 1
```